# hidesBarsOnSwipe will show toolbar unexpectedly

Tags: ios, swift, uitoolbar

I set `hidesBarsOnSwipe=true` in two view controllers, the Foo view controller which does not have a toolbar pushes Bar view controller which does have a toolbar. When Bar pop back to Foo, the toolbar will show when I scroll the Foo view controller. If I don't set `self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false` in Bar view controller, the toolbar will not show in neither Bar nor Foo view controller. I work with iOS8 SDK + Xcode 7.1.1 + Swift 2.1.

```
class FooTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = true
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "12345678"

    return cell
} }

class BarTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "12345678"

    return cell
}}
```

[image: Bar]
[image: Foo]

Comment: How did you solve your issue?

Answer (score -1):

You are up against 2 problems:

1. You cannot add anything to a `UITableViewController`
2. All the programmatic `toolbarHidden` and `hidesBarsOnSwipe` is only confusing the OS,and you will end up with toolbars on the wrong layer, scrolling along with the table view, and similar oddities with the navigation bar.

What you want is for the second table view to be handled by a `UIViewController`, not a `UITableViewController`. There is little programmatic change, you only need your `UIViewController` to adopt the data source and table delegate protocols.

No need to tinker with showing/hiding the toolbar. The code is much simpler, you can define everything not listed below in the **Storyboard**.

**Foo** (no toolbar):

```
class FooTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Foo \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Bar", sender: self)
    }
}
```

**Bar** (with toolbar):

```
class BarTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Bar \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }
}
```

**Final Product:**

[image: Foo & Bar]

---

► Find this solution on [GitHub](http://swiftarchitect.com/recipes) and additional details on [Swift Recipes](https://github.com/SwiftArchitect/SO-33863028).

Comment: I download your demo, and set "Hide Bars On Swipe" in Storyboard(set in navigation controller's Attributes inspector), then I found the navigation bar will disappear when I scroll the tableview in Bar view controller. Is there anything wrong? I need "Hide Bars On Swipe" feature to show more infomation. Thank you.